# Flickering Screen Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, screen

I have been experiencing a problem with the display of my laptop for month now. The screen keep flickering every time something moves fast on the screen.

Scrolling down a text, moving windows around or watching videos is very unpleasant.

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04.5 with kernel version 4.15.0-38.

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 graphics card and I am using the Nvidia proprietary driver (version 390.87) installed.
The issue was exactly the same when I was using the previous Nvidia driver (384.130).

I use Gnome as my desktop environment but I have tried Unity as well and the issue persists.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.